# Bathroom Ventilation Leaking

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, leaking

My ceiling leaks when it rains and it’s right where my bathrooms venting system is. My bathroom vents through a piping system in the attic and then out through the roof. The pipe that sticks of the roof has an elbow piece on it to keep rain water from falling in. Once I’m in the attic I follow the pipping to an elbow piece which appears to be the cause of my leak. My question is why is it leaking when it rains? The piece that is exposed to the outside appears to have signs of water damage. I’ve had a roofer and plumber come out and look. Roofer and plumber said the same  thing. There’s no sign of water damage on the roof or where the pipe comes out of the roof. And there’s no sign of water dripping down the pipe. Just at the elbow joint which plumber said it looks like it has been repaired before. Why is the pipe leaking when it rains? Where is the water coming from? Could it still be coming in through the elbow joint that is exposed to the outside?

Comment: we do not see anything

Comment: Rain water is probably entering the vent and is leaking thru a failing connection.   To test, tape a few sticks to the vent pipe protruding several 3-4 inches above the top of the vent pipe. then tape some plastic or tin foil over the top part, making sure there is still plenty of room for the vent to operate properly. If it doesn't leak anymore when it rains, you found the issue and the leaking connections need to be repaired.   If it still leaks, you have a flashing/roofing issue.

Comment: A photo, if possible,  would help